# Rational functions and residues

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, rational-functions

Suppose you have two rational  functions of x  having the same (finite) limit when x→ ∞, having the same simple poles and the same residues in these poles, does it imply that they're equal? How to show that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{100}+1}x$$
and $$g(x)=\frac{x^2+1}x$$

They both have simple pole at $0$.

The residues are both $1$.

They both tends to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty$.

But $$f(x)\ne g(x)$$

p.s. I am not sure what you mean by ‘same behaviour’. Do you specifically mean
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$?

Even you do mean that, just consider
$$\frac{x^2+x+1}x$$ and $$\frac{x^2+1}x$$

Comment: thank you, Yes you're right ! i think this  theorem is true in the case of finite limit  ie. if the limit of f(x) when x--->$\inf$ is not infinite, in this case i couldn't find a counterexample

Comment: @Giuseppe would you like to accept my answer?